# How to start the content from below of that fixed div?

Tags: css, html, position

I have a div whose position is fixed, which is displayed on the right side. I have lots of content and that content should start below the fixed div.

Is there any option when I set the fixed div that the content always starts from  below the fixed div?

```css
.parent_img{
 position: fixed;
 right: 0;
}
.content, .content_2, .content_3{
 width: 700px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_img">
 <img src="http://www.davidhill.co/wp-content/uploads/Free.jpg">
</div>

<div class="content">
 <h2>This is just for testing</h2>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>


<div class="content_2">
 <h2>This is just for testing 2</h2>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<div class="content_3">
 <h2>This is just for testing 3</h2>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<!--many more-->
```

**I am getting the output.**
[image]

**I need output like this**
[image]

Comment: If the position: fixed content has a fixed height, then you just need to add some padding/margin to the top of the content on the left. If the position: fixed content has a dynamic height, then you need JavaScript, as there is no way for static content to read the height of fixed content without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the height value of that fixed div (= the height of the image) as `margin-top` for the first content DIV.

In your case the image is 260px high, so use:

```
.content {
  margin-top: 260px;
}
```

In the following snippet I actually added 20px to create some more distance. I also added some other settings to the fixed DIV (see below) so that the content won't remain partly visible left or right of the image when being scrolled up.

```css
.parent_img{
 position: fixed;
 right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: right;
}
.content, .content_2, .content_3{
 width: 700px;
}
.content {
  margin-top: 280px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_img">
 <img src="http://www.davidhill.co/wp-content/uploads/Free.jpg">
</div>

<div class="content">
 <h2>This is just for testing</h2>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>


<div class="content_2">
 <h2>This is just for testing 2</h2>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<div class="content_3">
 <h2>This is just for testing 3</h2>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<!--many more-->
```

Comment: Another method (maybe less of a hack) would be to use ``position:relative`` on the ``div.content`` and then give it a ``top: insertheightofimgpx;``

Comment: No, I don't know the height of the div. I just added temporary

Comment: @NE555 No, that won't work: position: relative will move (actually *offset*) that one DIV by its top, but it will then overlap the subsequent elements. try it...

Comment: @Johannes, You mean to say  I have to set the hight for this class .parent_img?

Comment: @NarendraVerma no, that was a mistake I made, since the image determines the DIV height. But your image is 260px high, so you can use that as a top margin for the content DIV.

Comment: @Johannes, Can you create the snippet, So that I can understand  better Because I tried and CSS is working on both the div

Comment: @NarendraVerma I just added a snippet - note the remarks and additional changes I made.

Comment: Yes, I just remove the background-color. and it's working for me. Thanks for the help and upvote from my side.

Answer (score 0):

I have restructure your source code. Css modified

```css
.parent_img{
    position: fixed;
    float:right;  
    width:50%;
    right:0;
}

img{
    max-width:100%;
 }

.content, .content_2, .content_3{
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    margin-top:200px;
    text-align:justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_img">
 <img src="http://www.davidhill.co/wp-content/uploads/Free.jpg">
</div>

<div class="content">
 <h2>This is just for testing</h2>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>


<div class="content_2">
 <h2>This is just for testing 2</h2>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<div class="content_3">
 <h2>This is just for testing 3</h2>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<!--many more-->
```

Comment: he wants the image to be fixed in the upper right corner of the window when the content is scrolled...

Comment: @Verma can you check now.